# How to share data between two sidekiq workers'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, sidekiq

Imagine there are billions of users and each user can have multiple email id, the task is to send happy new year greetings to each and every user, in a minimal time.

There are two sidekiq workers
one worker fetches user's email id.

Another worker only send email notifications.

The thought process is to achieve parallelism one worker will only fetch user email and another worker will only send email.

Is there a way to achieve this using sidekiq

Comment: If really want to do this -- just use separate queues -- have the first worker read from one queue and feed the queue for the second worker. Though with billions of users this is not going to be enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed an optimization you can do, actually a few optimizations.

1. Get the actual information you need instead of the user ID so step 2 doesn't need to hit the database at all. IE: For a new years greeting, you will likely need the user's name (at least the first name) and their email address. The user ID is probably not helpful as you'll need to do a database query to look at the user to get the actual information you need. It is likely still useful to include it for other purposes though (see #3 below)
2. Pre-schedule as many emails as possible. Everything in Step 1 can be done well in advance of when you actually need to send the emails. However, it is possible that some users may be missed (likely a very small percentage), so...
3. Add columns to the database (or even an entire database table) to show if a user has had the New Year's greeting (or other holiday) emails queued to be sent. One column can be `new_years_greeting_email_queued_to_be_sent_at` and another can be `new_years_greeting_email_sent_at`. The first field is used to flag that the first worker has been run. The second field shows the second worker has run. Add a method you can run to fetch all the users that have not yet been queued for sending *this years* email (make sure to test this well). You can then run that in advance for #1 and then again after you have sent out all the advance emails to catch anyone who has joined after you did #1 above.
4. With #1 and #2 in mind, change the first worker so it just does a database query and populates ALL of the jobs for worker #2, again in advance.

The bigger issue is that two workers may not be enough. A work might process what 10K emails a second? It'll take a bit more than a day to finish (need greater than 12K emails a second to finish within a day). Now if you meant several million, then at that rate you should be able to finish in time. Even if you only send about 12 emails a second to finish within a day, and assuming you aren't getting rate limited, 100 or so emails a second should be doable without too much trouble.

Though you'll definitely need to coordinate with whatever service you are using to send emails to make sure it won't be an issue.

Warning: Be careful about the above method, if you have billions of emails to send (or even millions), you may exceed the storage limit of redis. In this case, you may need to skip #1 and just store IDs. If you are using Heroku or something similar, you may just be able to spin up additional dynos to handle it instead of using workers (#1 and #2 can still be done in advance just with the data stored in the database, then you can just do a `find_each` loop with a query to find which users still need their new years emails sent out.

Answer (score 1):

Just have one worker fetch an email id (whatever that means) and then in that worker enqueue another worker to send the email (passing the email id).